# Local, element-scoped style not applying to children

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-4.5

I'm a WPF beginner and I'm kind of stuck at figuring out why below XAML doesn't do what I believe it should:

```
<ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,250,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ToolBar.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,6" />
        </Style>
    </ToolBar.Resources>
    <Button Content="Save"/>
    <Button Content="Cancel"/>
    <Separator />
    <Button Content="Options"/>
</ToolBar>
```

This should cause the `<Separator />` to have the margins of `4,6` but it only does so if I explicitly specify `x:Key` on the style and the `<Separator Style="..." />`.

From what I learned so far, my `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">` should apply to all separators inside the `<ToolBar>`, its child elements, its children's children and so on.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `x:Key` to `{x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}` for the style be applied within a `ToolBar`:

```
<ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,250,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ToolBar.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,6" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </ToolBar.Resources>
    <Button Content="Save"/>
    <Button Content="Cancel"/>
    <Separator />
    <Button Content="Options"/>
</ToolBar>
```

This is because the `ToolBar` class contains some "special" logic for applying default styles to some type of controls including the `Separator`: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ToolBar.cs,5d1684510f45eeb3

Comment: Wow, thanks mm8! That solved the problem, I'll apply the same logic for other ToolBar elements I style later.